# Mousemove issue [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just created #element and #box which detect if it's out of the viewport. If so, it should go above the cursor but here's my issue. When #box is out of the viewport it starts acting weird by flashing over and over. Hope you guys can help me. Cheers.

```
var box = $("#box");
var element = $("#element");
var PAGEX;
var PAGEY;
var elementTop;
var elementBottom;
var windowHeight;

element.bind({
mousemove: function (e) {
box.show();

PAGEX = e.pageX;
PAGEY = e.pageY;

elementTop = box.offset().top;
elementBottom = elementTop + box.outerHeight();
windowHeight = $(window).height();

if(elementBottom > windowHeight)
{
  box.css({
    top: PAGEY - 65,
    left: PAGEX + 15
  })
}
else
{
  box.css({
    top: PAGEY + 15,
    left: PAGEX + 15
  })
}

},
mouseleave: function () {
box.hide();
}
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9Lon5jj/)

Comment: You're saying that if the element's bottom y position is greater than the window's height (ie, some of it is going off screen) then offset its position upwards. However, once this happens the element's y position is no longer beyond the viewport and so the offset is removed, causing the element once again to be beyond the viewport. Thus it flickers between these states. Measure the position of the cursor + box height instead.

Comment: Thank you @Moob for clarifying the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are doing your out-of-viewport check against the actual box location, rather than the location based on the mousemove.  So, this works the first time the box would move out of the viewport - you adjust it back inside.  But, the next time the mouse moves, your box is safely inside the viewport.  So your check adjusts it based on the mouse position, and it gets put outside the viewport.  The next time the mouse moves, the calculation works, and it gets adjusted back inside, and so on.

The fix is to change this:

```
if(elementBottom > windowHeight)
```

To this:

```
if(PAGEY + 15 + box.outerHeight() > windowHeight)
```

So that it is always calculating the out-of-viewport based on where the *target* location would be, and not where its current location is.

Comment: Cheers bud, I get it!